# Как привести объект к массиву (js/typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

После парсинга получаю такой объект с помощью JSON.stringify

```
[
  {
    "$": {
      "key": "v1",
      "value": "VS1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$": {
      "key": "v2",
      "value": "VS2"
    }
  }
]
```

Нужно привести его к интерфейсу `V[]`

```
export interface V {
    key: string;
    value: string;
}
```

Как это можно исключить `"$":` сделать?

В результате должно получится

```
[
  {
    "key": "v1",
    "value": "VS1"
  },
  {
    "key": "v2",
    "value": "VS2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, нужно получить новый массив, в котором каждому элементу соответствует элемент из старого.

Для такой операции нужно использовать метод [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
.map(el => el.$)
```

```js
console.log(
  [{
      "$": {
        "key": "v1",
        "value": "VS1"
      }
    },
    {
      "$": {
        "key": "v2",
        "value": "VS2"
      }
    }
  ].map(el => el.$)
)
```

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо!